# How to refer to related object field by name (string) in formula

Tags: formula, formula-field

Not sure if possible, but is there a way, within a Formula Field, to refer to a related object field by name, as a calculated string?  For example (this doesn't work):

```
Purchase_Price__r['Original_amount_'+$User.Reporting_Currency__c+'__c']
```

Where `Purchase_Price__c` is a lookup for the Currency Amount object, which has fields such as Original_amount_USD__c, Original_amount_CAD__c, etc; and where Reporting_Currency__c is a field on user that will contain USD, CAD, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in Salesforce. You can, however, create a field in the User object to track the user's preferred currency. Then, in the formula field, get the corresponding field with an IF formula.

*"If user's favourite currency is US dollars, then retrieve the field with USD amount."*

I didn't test this, but I think it would work. Of course, it would depend on both fields (CAD and USD) being filled with values, otherwise it wouldn't work if two users with different currencies tried to access the same object.

Comment: right, if I can't find a better way to do this, it will be a CASE statement.  But would rather have a cleaner way to do this.